# Changing hash fragment on scroll down Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am building a single page portfolio using Next JS.

I have different sections in my index.js file like below with links. When I scroll down the page, the url does not change to reflect the page it is on. But when I click on the link to the page from the nav bar, the url updates.

This is annoying say if I click to go to the skills page but scroll up or down. My url stays as "http://localhost:3000/#skills"

How do you fix this so the url changes on scroll.

````
<section
                id="intro"
            >
                <Hero />
            </section>
            <section
                id="about"
            >
                <About />
            </section>
            <section
                id="skills"
            >
                <Skills />
            </section>
            <section
                id="projects"
            >
                <Projects />
            </section>
            <section
                id="contact"
            >
                <Contact />
            </section>```


I have tried using router.asPath and window.location.hash but both still give me whatever the url is currently on as opposed to the page that I am on.
````